# 'Error: expected 422 "Unprocessable Entity", got 200 "OK"' node.js/ express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am constantly throwing the **below error**:

```
Error handling invalid query params:
Error: expected 422 "Unprocessable Entity", got 200 "OK"
```

---

below is my full `/app.js`.

```
'use strict'
var path = require('path');
var meal = require('./meals.js');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();

module.exports = function(app) {

  app.get('/allMeals', meal.getAllMeals, END);

  app.get('/meals/:id', meal.getMealinfo, END, function(req, res, next) {
      meal.findById(req.params.id).exec()
        .then(function(xxx) {
          if (meal == null) return next(); // Not found
          return res.send('Found meal '+request.params.id);
        })
        .then(null, function(err) {
          return next(err);
        });
  });

  app.get('/meals/:id/options',meal.getHealthymeals, END);

  function END(req,res){
    res.end();
  }  

  res.status(404).send({
   message: 'Router not found.'
  });

  });
};
```

**How could I better handle *my* invalid query params with node.js /express, to perhaps stop throwing this error?**

---

I have installed [express-validation](https://github.com/AndrewKeig/express-validation) - and would prefer this route to solving for the error; but I am unsure how to implement from the examples given.

```
 function invalidParamHandler(req, res, next, context) {
    const { error, oldQuery, nextQuery, droppedParams } = context;

    // Do 
    }

    app.use(queryValidator(invalidParamHandler));

  });
```

Comment: Have a look at http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html. You probably want to set up an error handling middleware.

Comment: Thanks for your input; yes, I've gotten that much.