# check for invalid query params then throw error in (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How could I check all invalid query params in my small node.js app; and if invalid query param is found, then simply throw error `(422).send...` ?

I have started with the below, but with no luck:

```
 //  function invalidParamHandler(req, res, next, context) {
 //    const { error, oldQuery, nextQuery, droppedParams } = context;
         // Do 
    // }
    // app.use(queryValidator(invalidParamHandler));
```

I have also tried.

```
  app.get('*', function(err, results){

  // if(err) return errors.log(err, "Had trouble retrieving users.");
    res.status(422).send({
       message: 'Invalid params found.'
      });

  });
```

*spawning from this question; ['Error: expected 422 "Unprocessable Entity", got 200 "OK"' node.js/ express app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966167/error-expected-422-unprocessable-entity-got-200-ok-node-js-express-app)*

Answer (score 0):

The best way to **check/ validate / sanitize the params/ body/ query/ header** is to use the [express-validator module](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator) instead of **express-validation**. It will through 400 error (bad request) by default or you can have a ***custom response status code*** for those requests.