# req.checkQuery(' '); & req.checkParams(' '); for validate -> error handle (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express, mocha.js

I am trying to use [express-validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator/blob/master/README.md#installation)'s

```
req.checkQuery('');
req.checkParams('');
```

To simply check/ validate and make sure my query params are valid. to pass this mocha error:

```
error handling handles invalid query params:
     Error: expected 422 "Unprocessable Entity", got 200 "OK"
```

I have tried in this context; I am not finding much documentation on these two, specifically. Any pointers on use of `checkQuery` and `checkParams`? Can I check through all queries and params with these?

```
 app.get('*', function(req, res) {

  req.checkQuery('');
  req.checkParams('');

  });
```

spawning from: ['Error: expected 422 "Unprocessable Entity", got 200 "OK"' node.js/ express app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966167/error-expected-422-unprocessable-entity-got-200-ok-node-js-express-app)